# How to clone an entire disk to a larger disk and then offload?

Tags: dd, file-copy, cloning, disk-image

What I have done is clone a small 32GB flash module that had three partitions. I happened to have a 32GB USB lying around, so I thought it *might* just work; it did not. It seems 32GB from Toshiba is a bit different than 32GB from Sandisk.

Anyway, so then took to a 2TB external drive and did the exact same thing. Specifically, I did the following:

`dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=100M`

**aside** Does the final block come across as a partial copy or is it dropped if EOF is reached first?

So as to essentially clone the entire flash module -- partition table and all. The 32GB -> 2TB was easy enough since the `dd` utility properly halted after reading through the end of the final (third) partition.

So, what I want to do now is just create a simple binary blob containing the entire flash image. My 2TB drive is now identically partitioned with respect to the original drive: `sdx1, sdx2, sdx3`. So, once again I just took to `dd` with the following:

`dd if=/dev/sdx of=firmware.bin bs=100M`

Doing so will not only copy the first 32GB I am interested in, but it will also continue on through and clone the entire 2TB drive, or so it did when I tried it. I can find the exact byte-length of the partitions of interest by the following:

```
$ lsblk -b
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM          SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdc                            8:32   0 2000398933504  0 disk  
├─sdc1                         8:33   0     134217728  0 part  
├─sdc2                         8:34   0    2147483648  0 part  
└─sdc3                         8:35   0   29734297600  0 part
```

A definite way to solve this would be to set the blocksize of `dd` to one byte and then set the number of blocks to read as the sum of the three sizes above:

`dd if=/dev/sdc of=firmware.bin bs=1 count=32015998976`

But I can't image how long that would actually take.

**EDIT**: A quick test of curiosity of the above showed a solid ~150KB/s transfer rate.

---

**tl;dr** How can I exclusively copy the first three partitions of a disk that is much larger than the sum of the partition sizes?

Comment: Any reason why not to make the block size 32015998976 and the count 1?

Comment: @Anthon, that working depends on it 'dd' first reads a block into memory before writing it, which the documentation seems to allude to. I certainly don't have 32GB of RAM to spare.

Comment: If you are not into buying more memory, 32015998976 can be nicely factored into 2^13x13x300631. Surely you can come up with a combination of block size and count that will fit in memory and is more efficient.

Comment: @Anthon, that was the next step if this question did not produce any simple solutions.

Comment: If you still have the original flash, wouldn't it be more easy to format the harddrive, mount it and then `dd` the flash to a file on the drive, possible one partition at a time?

Comment: @Anthon, the target device is an embedded platform with only 32GB of memory, being its own flash. I have USB access to it, so I can dd the contents off, but then I have to figure out how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the partitions that you need and the MBR if you need it too.

### The MBR is stored in the the first 512 bytes of the disk.

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/to/mbr_file.img bs=512 count=1
```

### Copy each partition

```
dd if=/dev/sdX1 of=/path/to/partition1.img bs=512

dd if=/dev/sdX2 of=/path/to/partition2.img bs=512

dd if=/dev/sdX3 of=/path/to/partition3.img bs=512
```